# Unable to use android:overlapAnchor with appcompat-v7:23.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lokesh.music.player.ui"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

**gradle file**

---

error : android:overlapAnchor Requires minimum API 21.
I'm using Min. API 16
How to resolve this error?
I'm newbiew to android so any help would be great

Comment: Change minSdkVersion to 21, if that's not what you want you should probably look for an older version of appcompat

Comment: If minSdkVersion is 21, there is no need to use Appcompat. I want the app to run on API 16 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `styles.xml`, use `<item name="overlapAnchor">...</item>`. And then create another `styles.xml` in `values-v21` folder. You can use `android:overlapAnchor` in this file.
Hope this will help you.